# PHP redirect user once file is uploaded with DropzoneJS

Tags: php, redirect, upload, dropzone.js

**Problem:**

PHP code does not redirect user to target page using header().

**Code (upload.php):**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $folder      = 'upload';

    if (!empty($_FILES))
    {
        // Set temporary name
        $tmp    = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        // Set target path and file name
        $target = $folder . '/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

        // Upload file to target folder
        $status = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);

        if ($status)
        {
            // Set session with txtfile name
            $_SESSION['txtfile'] = $_FILES['file']['name'];

            // Redirect user
            header('Location: explorer.php');   
        }
    }
?>
```

**Desired functionality:**

Get header() to work to redirect user to explorer.php. Yes, the file is successfully uploaded without any problem. But user continue to stay on the same page (upload.php).

Comment: Is $status true? If so you need to exit();

Comment: @SajunaFernando I have added a exit() after header without any success.

Comment: Try this:

try{
 $status = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);
}catch(Exception $oException){
   var_dump($oException); die;
}

Comment: @SajunaFernando Just did, the file got uploaded and nothing more.

Comment: Check your error log. Is it empty or are there any errors?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. Just checked it.

Comment: Try adding `ob_start()` just under `session_start()`. If this works, something is outputting data before the `header()` call and for it to work, nothing must be outputted. `ob_start()` will prevent it from outputting right away and save it in an output buffer.

Comment: Added ob_start() under session_start() and upload worked correctly. No redirection.

Comment: Is your opening `<?php` tag at the beginning of the file or are there any other characters on front of it? Even a single space will prevent the `header()` call from functioning properly. Also, sometimes (when changing file encoding or using a bad editor) some garbage can appear before the opening tag which might not be visible in your editor. Try opening your file with several different editors to check there is no garbage at the beginning. Also try adding a couple random letters to the start and then removing them so the invisible stuff disappears. Hit the backspace a couple extra times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$status = false;
if (is_uploaded_file($tmp) == true) {
   $status = @move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);
}
else {
    $status = @copy($tmp, $target);
}

if(file_exists($target)){
    $status = true;
}

if ($status)
{
    // Set session with txtfile name
    $_SESSION['txtfile'] = $_FILES['file']['name'];

     // Redirect user
     header('Location: explorer.php');   
 }
```

Comment: Just tried this solution and nothing happens after upload. The file gets uploaded and no errors in the error_log.

Comment: can you add this to the top of your script, just to be sure and try again: ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Added both error handlers. No errors when uploading file. Just considering dumping DropzoneJS and go with some other jQuery uploading file. Feels too much hassle for such a problem.

Comment: I would var_dump the $_FILES array to be sure you recieve the file. Then remove the session storing part for a bit. Apart from that your code looks fine

Comment: Tried it, nothing happens and the file does get uploaded as usual. I know this information is not much but I'm confused as well.

Comment: Is it even coming to your script file?

Comment: I assume it does because I empty the folder and when I upload the file it gets saved to the folder.